# The dicom bufferedImage from pixelmed is having low contrast

Tags: java, jframe, bufferedimage, dicom

I would like to display a DICOM image in my java program. I am using pixelmed. However, I found that i cant correctly display the correct contrast. The contrast is too low.

Here is my code:

(SourceImage is a class provided by PixelMed, chosenImageFile.getPath() is just the path of the DICOM File.)

```
SourceImage dimg = new SourceImage(chosenImageFile.getPath());
BufferedImage image = dimg.getBufferedImage();

BufferedImage source = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

Graphics2D g2d = source.createGraphics();
g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
dicomImgDisplayer1.setImage(source);
```

dicomImgDisplayer1 is an class extend JPanel. setImage() of this JPanel class will call the setImage() of an JFrame class.

The JFrame class's setImage() code:

```
public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
   this.image = image;
   setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
   repaint();
   revalidate();
}

public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
   g2d.drawImage(image, null, 0, 0);
}
```

Is that something wrong with the color model? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Does the image look different in another application or are you assuming that the contrast is wrong? What's the color model of the original image?

Comment: @Nanhydrin, I don't know the color model. But it looks different when i open it in another application.

Comment: You can always try to print the color model (ie.: `System.out.println(source.getColorModel())`), to see if that gives us some clues. And maybe post some screen shots, comparing "another application" with yours? Have you tried using `ColorConvertOp` instead of just painting onto an RGB `BufferedImage`? It might be more accurate in ICC color transformations.

Comment: Does anyone know if the line g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); actually converts from one color model to another, or how does it work?

Comment: @Nanhydrin I know that if I have a `BufferedImage` with a CMYK color model and drawing it onto a `BufferedImage` with RGB color model, it will be converted (and it will be slow ;-)). But not sure if actually uses `ColorConvertOp` behind the scenes, or if a different conversion is performed.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that @haraldK. User3241775, what happens if you change the color model of source to TYPE_BYTE_GRAY or TYPE_USHORT_GRAY (I would expect the actual image to be >8 bit grayscale)?

Answer (score 0):

Does your image have a prescribed window width / window center? Be sure you set that (or allow the user to adjust it). See [SingleImagePanel](http://www.dclunie.com/pixelmed/software/javadoc/com/pixelmed/display/SingleImagePanel.html) - there are some static methods to apply windowing to your buffered image.